# Why doesn't Skype start?

Tags: skype

I downloaded and installed [Skype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skype), but by clicking the icon it just does not start.

What should I do?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Take a look in the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) , try also to give additional information. what version  of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 11):

It's always good to open a terminal and issue the command from there. Failure will at the least reports some output.

Open a terminal and issue the command:

`skype`

Comment: skype didn't start from `Ubuntu Software -> Launch`, but it perfectly started from terminal

Comment: what is the command to open skype from the terminal?

Comment: I installed Skype from an rpm with yum on CentOS 7.2 and it wouldn't start. The `skypeforlinux` command shows no terminal output.

Answer (score 10):

Just to be sure. You downloaded and installed Skype through **Ubuntu's Software Center**.

I recommend doing it this way. But in all cases, Skype has a particular issue that if you start it 2 or more times it gets stuck if you did not close it properly.

Do the following in a terminal:

`sudo killall skype` or `sudo killall -9 skype`. That should force skype to close even if you do not see it. It kills the Skype process.

After which I also recommend putting the Skype icon in the Launcher. This way, if you double click on it, it will not open twice. It will just open normally and the second click will make it get focus.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem. Followed the answer here https://askubuntu.com/a/322347/115308, and it is working now.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you install 32-bit / 64-bit Skype on respective hardware.  Installing from the Ubuntu Software Center automatically decides what version is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

When starting Skype, a native 32 bit binary, in a 64 bit environment you might run into the following error and Skype refuses to start:

> skype: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

So far I only had this problem on 64 bit. The following solution solved it:

```
# ln -s /usr/lib/mesa-diverted/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
```

---

*Source : https://wiki.debian.org/skype#Problems_starting_Skype*

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the problem was posted in such a general form makes it applicable to recent developments.

**In Kubuntu 18.04** downloading and installing the deb file I can only start it once, log in, without any way of accessing contacts etc. Closing and restarting it appeared in tray but would not start. Running `skype` in terminal it says uninstalled, recommends to use

```
sudo snap install skype
```

Doing that (after uninstalling `skypeforlinux`) it asks me to use

```
sudo snap install skype --classic
```

which successfully installs a working Skype.