# Skype 4.2 in Ubuntu 13.04 won't open in nVidia Optimus Laptops

Tags: nvidia, skype, nvidia-optimus

Actually this is an answer. Im not asking a question. Last day, I tried to install skype 4.2 on my dell N5110 with nvida Optimus, after the installation when I tried to open skype from dash it didn't open. So then I opened it with Terminal via `skype` and it gave me an error `error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

So I did the following steps with the help of method mentioned in [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257897/error-loading-libgl-so-1).

Steps:

1. Open a terminal and type `sudo nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/skype.conf`
2. Add the code `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/` in the next console window, and press ctrl+x to exit, when prompted enter y to say yes
3. And finally run `sudo ldconfig -v`

Comment: sudo find / -name libGL.so.1 > output ?

Comment: have you checked http://askubuntu.com/questions/285642/skype-crashes-with-a-segmentation-fault/285916#285916

Comment: The only thing that worked for me was to remove the NVIDIA driver: `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-304`.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) We're sorry, but Ubuntu 13.04 is an end-of life product and is not supported any more, so it's off-topic here too.  Please refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Upgrades on how to upgrade.

Comment: A straightforward application of our EoL policy [would not justify closing a question like this, as 13.04 was non-EoL when this was asked](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8188), so I've voted to leave this open. At the same time, if people think the details of this question indicate it will never be even slightly useful to anyone running any supported (or future) release, I do see (though not agree with) a cogent case for closing it. If that's the reasoning for closure, I suggest someone explain in detail.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

Install the package libgl1-mesa-glx:i386

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

Launch Skype via:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 skype &
```

You can put the last statement into a shell script, e.g. ~/bin/skype , or create a .desktop-File with this content:

```
Name=Skype
Terminal=false
Exec=LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 skype
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

[UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles)

Answer (score 3):

Try this (NVIDIA Optimus Ubuntu 13.10):

```
$sudo update-alternatives --config i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf

  Selection           Path                                      Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/nvidia-331/alt_ld.so.conf         8604      auto mode

  1            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf    500       manual mode

  2            /usr/lib/nvidia-331-prime/alt_ld.so.conf   8603      manual mode

  3            /usr/lib/nvidia-331/alt_ld.so.conf         8604      manual mode


Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: **1** (Choose native value 1)

$  sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: This worked for me with `Bumbleebee` installed on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

[Thomas R](https://askubuntu.com/a/433260/60085)'s answer is right, but the desktop file did not work for 14.04.1 LTS 64bit.

Here's what works for me:

1. Edit file `/usr/share/applications/skype.desktop`
2. Change the line `Exec=env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60 skype %U` to `Exec=env LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60 skype %U`
3. Save file

Here's my complete `skype.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Skype
Comment=Skype Internet Telephony
Exec=env LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60 skype %U
Icon=skype.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Categories=Network;Application;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/skype;
X-KDE-Protocols=skype
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to enter in the terminal:

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

and then enter in the terminal:

```
 sudo apt-get install libgl-mesa-glx:i386
```

and then enter in the terminal this:

```
 sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a /etc/ld.so.conf.d/Skype.conf
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: This will never work.