# skype install on ubuntu 14.04 dependency hell

Tags: apt, package-management, skype, empathy

im trying to install skype since empathy and pidgin doesnt work so im stuck in the installation, anything seems to work, i tried using synaptics, gdeb with the packages from the page, even tried everything in  here too

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2229249

but nothing seems to work!

libqtwebkit4:i386 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 o
                              libgl1:i386
                     Depends: libqt4-opengl:i386 (>= 4:4.5.3) but wont be intalled

anyone has an idea to what can i do?

of course i already tried 
sudo apt-get -f install too

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it too much complex. Just download skype from its official website. Click [here](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/) to download and choose your distribution (for you, its **Ubuntu 12.04 (multiarch)** ). A debian file will be downloaded and your just a double-click away from installing skype. Enjoy!

Comment: man, already tried! it keeps happening the same thing i already downloaded that one and the debian only one and the ubuntu 10 32 too!

Comment: Have you able to use sudo apt-get install for other packages after trying to install skype ??

Comment: actually yes! :(

Comment: your running in 32 bit or 62?

Comment: 64 bits man sorry, didnt specified that one

Comment: So the architecture may be a problem (i368 is for 32 bit). If this is the problem, installing ia32-libs package can solve the case. Let us know if this solves the issue

Comment: so i tried to install those libraries and i got a lot more dependencies problems now

Comment: sooo i installed intel drivers and it worked! thanks man @harirehm

Answer (score 0):

Canonical has made the latest Skype 4.3 into the partners repository.
I've followed [these steps by ubuntuhandbook.org](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/skype-4-3-install-in-ubuntu-1404/) and they work.

1. Remove other version of skype first, type this in a terminal `sudo apt-get remove skype skype-bin && rm -rf ~/.skype`
2. Open **Software & Updates** and enable Canonical partners repository under Other Software tab.[image]
3. Install Skype `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype`

If you still can't run skype and you have NVidia graphic card, see [my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/603563/60085)