# Skype 4.2 freezes, force quits, and cannot re-start. Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, skype

I have Skype 4.2 on Ubuntu 13.04. Sometimes, Skype randomly freezes. I have to Force Quit it. I try to re-start Skype, its icon on Unity blinks to indicate it's loading. But nothing happens. The background of the icon turns back to transparent. It can't re-start. I have to shutdown my PC and restart Ubuntu, it's very tedious. Is there a way around this so that I don't have to restart my whole PC just to re-start Skype?

Comment: Skype 4.2 has been much on the recieving side of a lot of problem... they have fixed those issues and released a one which you can read about and also download from the link given in that page.. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/05/skype-for-linux-4-2-released

Comment: Like the OP, I'm already running Skype 4.2 (4.2.0.11). It's this new version that freezes.

Comment: For Ubuntu 13.10 users, look at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1197395

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use System Monitor, to kill the Skype process

[image]

Or, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo killall skype -s 9
```

Answer (score 0):

From this [article](http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Where-can-I-download-old-version-of-skype-for-Linux/td-p/913586) you can go to this [link](http://download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu_2.2.0.35-1_i386.deb) and get the old 2.2.0 version of skype which is rock solid stable. Some day skype will start making solid code again, but 4.2 has been just awful.

Answer (score 0):

Here are steps you can try, in increasing order of desperation. A combo of 1-3 worked for me!

1. logout & reboot.
2. apt-get update & upgrade.
3. apt-get autoremove & install.
4. install missing libraries for 32-bit mode ([suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/a/67902/5786)).
5. check display alternatives ([suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/a/322347/5786)).