# Skype video freeze

Tags: video, skype, freeze

Ubuntu 12.04

been skype(ing) with skype version 4.2something and its been fine, Had an an email from skype saying that I needed to update to new version skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb if I wished to continue logging into skype.

Since installing the upgrade on my pc the video of me on the remote pc freezes after about 5seconds and stays frozen until switching the video off and on my end, it will animate for again 5ish seconds before freezing again, this did not happen while I was using the 4.2 version.

I cant find a 4.2 version to revert back to and the one in the software centre appears to be an old beta too old to work.

The only adjustment I can find for skype video is check or uncheck auto exposure which makes no difference to the freezing.

At my end there seems no perceptible difference between versions, its ok but the video freezing on the remote pc is a consequence of my version upgrade.

Grateful for any suggestions of a fix

Comment: Same thing on 14.04. There was a bug on LP, I'll add the link later

Answer (score 0):

Since I upgraded to 14.04 Skype and VLC among others have not worked properly for me too.

VLC video was not appearing, and I managed to fix it by changing the output (it is in the preferences).

For Skype:
I have read different posts online, most of them suggest it is an issue with Open GL or the graphic card. I still have not managed to solve it but a good starting point is this post:
**https://askubuntu.com/a/386737/176483**

or possibly removing the video card drivers and installing a newer version.

I hope this helps even the slightest.