# Why won't Skype start in 13.10?

Tags: software-center, 13.10, skype

I have installed Skype using the Software Center but it won't start - nothing happens when I start it. I already reinstalled without success and I am running a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10.

And when I type `skype` into a terminal, I get:

```
skype: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared
  object file: No such file or directory
```

When I type `dpkg -l skype` in the terminal, I get this:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  skype          4.2.0.11-1   i386         Wherever you are, wherever they a
adriaan@Adriaan-Buijtendorp:~$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error:

```
libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file
```

...suggests that you do not have the shared library `libGL.so.1` installed. This library is provided by [one of these packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=saucy&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libGL.so.1).

If you have an AMD video card, try installing [fglrx [image: Install fglrx]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/fglrx).

If you have an Nvidia video card, try installing [nvidia-319 [image: Install nvidia-319]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nvidia-319).

Comment: well installing the video driver didn´t work but thanks for pointing me in the right direction http://askubuntu.com/a/322347/214128 is the answer i found after googling