# Some Steam games won't start up, gameoverlayrenderer.so error

Tags: 14.10, games, steam, segmentation-fault

I'm using an Intel HD Graphics card.

For the last few days, for an unknown reason, some Steam games won't start up, including Half-Life and Garry's Mod.

Here's the shell output with Half-Life:

```
Game update: AppID 70 "Half-Life", ProcID 28160, IP 0.0.0.0:0  
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/s0/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.  
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/s0/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.  
pid 28164 != 28163, skipping destruction (fork without exec?)  
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/s0/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.  
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/s0/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.  
Generating new string page texture 399: 128x256, total string texture memory is 3,84 MB  
Using breakpad crash handler  
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 70  
Forcing breakpad minidump interfaces to load  
Looking up breakpad interfaces from steamclient  
Calling BreakpadMiniDumpSystemInit  
Looking up breakpad interfaces from steamclient  
Calling BreakpadMiniDumpSystemInit  
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561198056430718 [API loaded yes]  
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Setting Steam ID:  76561198056430718  
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/s0/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.  
assert_20150621233104_1.dmp[28171]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20150621233104_1.dmp  
/home/s0/.local/share/Steam/SteamApps/common/Half-Life/hl.sh : line 38 : 28166 Segmentation fault  (core dumped) ${DEBUGGER} "${GAMEROOT}"/${GAMEEXE} $@   
Game removed: AppID 70 "Half-Life", ProcID 28166
```

I've tried removing all the Steam Runtime libraries, but nothing changed.

Comment: have you tried disabling the steam overlay for these games - right click in your library on the game - go to properties, then uncheck  - enable the steam overlay while in game.

Comment: Yeah, did not work. Same with globally removing it. It also caused more problems (alt+tab would crash TF2 for example).

Comment: I googled the error, [here's a forum post that may help.](https://github.com/GhostSquad57/Steam-Installer-for-Wheezy/issues/37)

Answer (score -3):

You need the 32 bit libGL drivers (libgl1-mesaa-dri:i386).

You can issue this command via terminal,

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
```

If you already have it, try reinstalling,

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
```

Restart your computer and try again.

If that doesn't work, check out this: [Error loading libGL.so.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257897/error-loading-libgl-so-1)

Comment: Are you sure? It's not talking about libGL.so.1 in the log...

Comment: ld.so is a part of the libGL.

Comment: The other link did not help either, as the "best choice" for libGL.so.1 is already picked.

Comment: ld.so is the dynamic linker. It has nothing specific to do with libGL.

Comment: @woahguy  ld.so is the dynamic linker as ams points out.