# Skype Breaks Pulse & Bumblebee, badly. Awesome. 15.04

Tags: nvidia, sound, pulseaudio, skype, bumblebee

Installing skype from the partner repositories. Try to start Skype. It fails. Search online. Find this person with the same error message:

[Error loading libGL.so.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257897/error-loading-libgl-so-1) and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype

Follow instructions in first answer with similar error reported in console. This was what I typed:

`update-alternatives --display i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf`

`sudo update-alternatives --config i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf`

(switched to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf (option "1") from these options:

```
Selection Path Priority Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0 /usr/lib/nvidia-304-updates/alt_ld.so.conf 9701 auto mode
* 1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf 500 manual mode
  2 /usr/lib/nvidia-304-updates/alt_ld.so.conf 9701 manual mode
```

then ran `sudo ldconfig`.

Fixes skype issues! Sound works, skype works.

Later:

Restart computer.

Damn.

No ability to adjust sound through pulse, only through alsamixer... the sound icon in the top right is greyed out, and system settings sound stuff has no effect... and, on top of that, skype sound is broken for playback, as well (though it does at least *start*, which is did not do before I used the AU fix listed above).

`ps aux | grep pulseaudio` returns nothing, and `pulseaudio -D doesn't work`

Anyone able to explain what's going on?

output from running `pulseaudio`:

```
E: [pulseaudio] ltdl-bind-now.c: Failed to open module /usr/lib/pulse-6.0/modules/module-bluetooth-policy.so: /usr/lib/pulse-6.0/modules/module-bluetooth-policy.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to open module "module-bluetooth-policy".
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.
```

The bluetooth is a red herring, I have that intentionally disabled on restart. That has not broken the sound before, it wasn't until skype that it broke.

noticed that 'additional drivers' had me set to nvidia proprietary driver now, so tried to change that back to X.org Nouveau... That was hard, it wouldn't let me (I would restart and it would be right back on nvidia). Finally it let me be on nouveau. But I had installed and setup bumblebee previously... Maybe that's the source of my problem? But sound used to work on nouveau, even... So frustrating...

Have also tried purging pulseaudio from instructions on another ubuntu answer, then reinstalling. Now this is what I see:

```
kajo@kajo-Latitude-E6530:~$ pulseaudio
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup without any loaded modules, refusing to work.
```

For now I've reported a bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1474173

:(

UPDATE:

I finally just reinstalled, and thought based on other solutions in that same thread that installing skype before bumblebee might fix my issues. So, I reinstalled. Installed skype.

Skype works! Sound works! No config options even needed!

Restarted computer.

Pulse is broken.

Skype doesn't work.

Installed Bumblebee. Normally, this fixes my 'brightness' fn key functionality (which doesn't work out of the box on ubuntu, I think it's a nouveau bug). This time, it doesn't (including after a restart).

I try 'optirun skype', the command to run it under the nvidia card on bumblebee, according to yet another answer on that page. I get this output, suggesting, as I thought, that bumblebee isn't running:

```
@:/etc/X11$ optirun skype
[  869.631200] [ERROR]The Bumblebee daemon has not been started yet or the socket path /var/run/bumblebee.socket was incorrect.
[  869.631265] [ERROR]Could not connect to bumblebee daemon - is it running?
```

this is my log from nvidia:

```
kajo@kajo-6530:~$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep nvidia
[     6.225] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[     6.225] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[     6.225] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[     6.225] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[     6.225] (II) Unloading nvidia
[     6.225] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[     6.231] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[     6.231] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[     6.231] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[     6.231] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[     6.231] (II) Unloading nvidia
[     6.231] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
kajo@kajo-6530:~$ grep Driver /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

I still kind of wonder if I install bumblebee first, but then use `optirun skype` for it, and don't change any system options, if I would be fine, but I'm loathe to reinstall my system yet again.

Comment: I did a fresh install, tried to reinstall skype on a nearly fresh machine. updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this problem, at least for the pulseaudio part.

Following [the wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype) one should install both `skype` and `pulseaudio:i386`. This is **WRONG**.

The latter is the problematic one, because removes the following packages

```
pulseaudio:amd64
pulseaudio-module-x11:amd64
rtkit:amd64
pulseaudio-utils:amd64
```

Adding them again

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio:amd64 pulseaudio-module-x11:amd64 rtkit:amd64 pulseaudio-utils:amd64
```

and allowing the removal of their `i386` counterparts solved the problem for me.

Please note that in this way Skype works (at least with the test call), so there is no need to install `pulseaudio:i386` at all.

I'll try to modify the wiki accordingly.